# Is the relative interior of a hyperplane equal to the hyperplane itself?

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis

Let $H = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n  \mid a^Tx = b\}$. Is the relative interior of $H$ equal to $H$ itself? By relative interior I mean the interior of the set within the affine hull of $H$.

My guess: I would expect that the affine hull of the hyperplane is the hyperplane itself. Thus, we are in the usual topology of $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ where $H$ is open, meaning $ri(H) = H$.

Comment: The affine hull of a hyperplane is the hyperplane itself.  Try to prove it yourself!

Comment: If this is true, then are the other steps that I outlined correct?

Comment: @Carlos I think you've got the right idea but may be missing some details here. Since $H$ is not actually in $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ it's not technically correct (perhaps I think you mean to use a notion like isomorphism?). The affine hull is certainly itself, it's just the topological part that needs a tweak

Comment: Yes I am confused in the topological part. I would like to say that we will always be able to find neighborhoods intersecting with the hyperplane because it is like we were looking at an open subset (or the whole?) of $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the proof. I original wanted to construct a continuous map from $H$ to $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ but I guess it is simpler than that.

Let $\langle a, x \rangle := a^T x$ and $\text{aff}(H)$ denote the affine hull of hyperplane.

**Proof.** It is obvious that $H \subset \text{aff}(H)$. Let $y \in \text{aff}(H)$. Then we may write it as a linear combination of elements in $H$ by definition:

$$
y = \sum^k_{i=1} \lambda_i x_i
$$
for some $k > 0$ and $\sum^k_{i=1} \lambda_i = 1$. Then just do a simple substitution:
$$
\langle a, y \rangle = \langle a, \sum^k_{i=1} \lambda_i x_i \rangle = \sum^k_{i=1} \lambda_i \langle a,   x_i \rangle = b \sum^k_{i=1} \lambda_i = b
$$
Thus, $\text{aff}(H) = H$.

Now, clearly the relative interior of $H$ is contained in $H$. On the other hand, let $x \in H$, it is obvious that
$$
\forall \epsilon > 0, B(x, \epsilon) \cap H \subset H
$$
Thus, $x$ is in the relative interior and the latter equals $H$.

Comment: well done, can you approve your own answer?